# MessageBeep thread Blocking

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to play alert sound per minute while my code is executing, does the `MessageBeep()` function blocks current thread? I was using `Beep()` call earlier which is of blocking type. Any blocking API call would be problematic in this scenario.

Usually sound played by `MessageBeep()` are so short that I cannot reliable tell whether it is synchronous or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356(v=vs.85).aspx):

> After queuing the sound, the MessageBeep function returns control to
>   the calling function and plays the sound asynchronously.

As you can see, it doesn't block.